# Doing calculations in Excel Online with user permission "View Only"

Tags: permissions, excel, excel-services

I want to share Excel files in a SharePoint library.

1. The users shall only be able to open the files in "Excel Online", but not to download them or the open them offline. Also the original file shall not be changed.

   I've solved that by assigning permission level `View Only`.
2. Nevertheless the users shall be able to use the basic Excel functionality (e.g. change cell values for doing calculations).

Is it possible to comply with point 2, without infringing point 1?

Answer (score 1):

Technically the users having view only permissions doesn't have ability to edit any items.So it is not possible to have view only users to edit the items.